# 'When' or 'where' in the title of TV series' episodes

Tags: word-usage

I've been watching the series *Friends* for a decade now, and I've suddenly noticed that in the titles of the episodes, it's always "the one **where** S + V" instead of "the one **when** S + V". I wonder if "when" is grammatical and why they used "where" here when actually, they were referring to a story happening at a point in time.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Both wh- words are "metaphorical". Just because a TV episode has a time duration (and may be *broadcast / streamed* at some particular time) doesn't necessarily mean we have to locate its *characteristics* in time rather than space. You wouldn't ask *Which is the Harry Potter book **when** Dumbledore dies?* For this purpose, books and TV episodes are metaphorical ***places*** where narratives are played out.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's the answer.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/where) shows that "where" isn't just used with place. It's very common with circumstances, situations, points in time, etc, e.g. "the size where traffic is a problem", "where the plan leads" (not necessarily a literal place), "kept that horse and gentled him to where I finally rode him" (the point at which). The common usage of "the book/film/episode where" is related to this.

Comment: What titles, for example?

Comment: I think ever since it started, *every* episode of *Friends* has had a title of the general form *The One Where...,* as the OP points out. I don't know if any other series before or since has adopted the style. Maybe the *Friends* copyright holders have dibs on it, and are holding out for higher payouts!

Answer (score 2):

Both wh- words in OP's examples are "metaphorical". Just because a TV episode has a time duration (and may be *broadcast / streamed* at some particular time) doesn't necessarily mean we have to locate its characteristics in *time* rather than *space*. Bear in mind you wouldn't ask...

> *Which is the Harry Potter book **when** Dumbledore dies?*

For OP's context, books and TV episodes are metaphorical ***places*** where narratives "take place" (are played out, enacted).

Comment: @KenAdams It could be seen as a colloquial extension of the perhaps more literal "in which," as in the titles of chapters in the "Winnie-the-Pooh" stories, e.g. "In which Eeyore has a birthday." Within the narrative, the only thing Eeyore is "in" is the Hundred Acre Wood, but *outside* the narrative, from a literary perspective, the event is "in" the chapter.

Comment: @AndyBonner: I'm with John Lawler (well - *not*, since sadly he's no longer with *us*). *"All language is metaphor",* so you're just switching from a temporal or spatial metaphor to a *container* metaphor. Offhand I can't think of any others that might be used to "locate" a narrative (e.g. - *surface* metaphor?), but they probably do exist.